# Tensorflow 1.0 LSTM Cell in dynamic_rnn throws dimension error

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to implement an LSTM Model as a model_fn input to an Estimator. My X is only a .txt with a time series of prices. Before going into my first hidden layer, I try to define the lstm cell as:

```
  def lstm_cell():
   return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
   size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)
  attn_cell = lstm_cell
  if is_training and keep_prob < 1:
   def attn_cell():
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
    lstm_cell(), output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
  cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([attn_cell() for _ in  range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)
  initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, data_type())
  inputs = tf.unstack(X, num=num_steps, axis=0)  
  outputs = []
  outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs,
                           initial_state=initial_state)
```

This then is supposed to go into:

```
  first_hidden_layer = tf.contrib.layers.relu(outputs, 1000)
```

Unfortunately, it throws an error idicating that                         "ValueError: Dimension must be 1 but is 3 for 'transpose' (op:                'Transpose') with input shapes: [1], [3]."
I gather that my problem is the "inputs" tensor. In its description, the inputs variable is supposed to be a tensor with form [batch_size,max_time,...], but Ihave no idea how to translate this into above structure since, through the estimator, only input values X and target values y are fed to the system. So my question would be how to create a tensor that can serve as an inputs variable to the dynamic_rnn class.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't need the line:

```
inputs = tf.unstack(X, num=num_steps, axis=0)
```

you can supply `X` directly to `dynamic_rnn` since `dynamic_rnn` doesn't take a list of tensors; It takes one tensor where the time axis is dimension 0 (if `time_major == True`) or dimension 1 (if `time_major == False`).

Actually, it seems that `X` has 2 dimensions only, since `inputs` is list of 1 dimensional tensors (as indicated by the error message). so you should replace the `unstack` line with:

```
inputs = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=2)
```

This will add a 3rd dimension of size 1 that is needed by `dynamic_rnn`

Comment: It works, so I am very obliged to you, but I don't quite understand it yet. It says that the "inputs" variable must be of form "[batch_size,time_steps,....]". However, my X is just a numpy array when I hand it over to the estimator which obviusly makes a tensor out of it with two dimensions. So my question would be what the second one is and where it comes from and in what sense this and the "tf.expand_dims()" command create the form "[batch_size,time_steps,....]"?

Comment: I think based on your question, you have a sequence of prices (lets say it is of length T). dynamic_rnn can work with multiple sequences at once "Batch" (lets say it is of size B). if you wish to supply one sequence only, set B to be 1. so the input should be of shape [B, T] but dynamic_rnn expects one more dimension (useful in other tasks like NLP where each word is a vector). since we must have that extra dimension but don't need it for a sequence of prices, we set it to 1. so the input shape is [B, T, 1]. if time_major is True, it should be [T, B, 1]. expand_dims adds that extra dimension.

Comment: I understand the last part, but my problem is to understand how to set B. Like I said, I only supply a time series in a 1-dimensional numpy array to the estimator. The only time I tell the system the batch_size is when I define the initial_state variable. That also leads to the inconvenience that my loss function, which looks like this:

Comment: "loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, predictions)"   , throws another dimension error because predictions obviously has batch_size and y has the original size. If I want to get the corresponding y-values, I would have to know which values of X were chosen. I guess my question really boils down to not understanding how tensorflow transforms the initial numpy array to fulfill the requirements of the dynamic_rnn and that way I "lose sight of it".

Comment: I also don't understand how (and why) tensorflow adds a dimension to the numpy array since I never supplied a graph with data except through placeholders. can you tell me the shapes of x and y? (x.shape and y.shape)

Comment: It says:"(?, 1)"

Comment: The "inputs" variable shape is "(?, 1, 1)", so as you said, it adds a third dimension with value 1. But the second one is 1, too, so if I understand this correctly, the "time_steps" and the "..." entries are "1" each and the "?" are the values from "X" in "batch_size".

Comment: so x is just vector but it seems that x was defined not as a 1D tensor but a 2D tensor. if I understood correctly, the 1st axis '?' is the time axis. we can change the expand_dims op to become: inputs = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=0). this way the inputs shape will be (1,?,1). where 1 is the batch size and ? is the time length and 1 is the data size. the output of the dynamic_rnn should become of shape (1,?,size).